# Android: Wait with super.onPause until button is pressed

Tags: android, save, wait, onpause

I want to save my program if it's going to shut down or in Pause mode.
I've created a funcion with name `save`. But now my question is, how can I wait with the `super.onPause()` method until the `save` button in my dialog is pressed?
Here my code:

```
@Override 
    public void onPause()
    {


         AlertDialog.Builder builder2=new AlertDialog.Builder(rechner.this);
         builder2.setMessage("Möchten sie ihre Noten Speichern?");
         builder2.setPositiveButton("OK",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
              save();
                 }
              });

            builder2.setNegativeButton("Nein Danke!", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
             public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Danke, dass sie mein Programm verwendet haben", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             onDestroy();
             }});
             builder2.setTitle("Speichern");
             builder2.show();
           //wait until somethin clicked
            super.onPause();    

    }
```

Hope you can help my and sorry for the bad english ;)

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to go ahead and say *you can't*.  At the very least, you *shouldn't*.  For things to run smoothly, Android needs to be able to shut down your app whenever needs to.  What if you get a phone call and you try to show a popup when the user wants to answer the phone?  Not going to be a happy camper.

You can probably override the *back button* action to show your popup if you really need it.

Also, pausing probably shouldn't be final.  Save the state temporarily and come back to it `onResume()`.

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer.
You're right, override the onStop method isn't  really a intelligent idea ;)
I'm going to override the back button. 
Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you put this line: "super.onPause();" into click listener? Like:

```
@Override 
public void onPause()
{
     if(pauseAlreadyClicked) {
         super.onPause();
     } else {

     AlertDialog.Builder builder2=new AlertDialog.Builder(rechner.this);
     builder2.setMessage("Möchten sie ihre Noten Speichern?");
     builder2.setPositiveButton("OK",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
          save();
          pauseAlreadyClicked = true;
          onPause();
             }
          });

        builder2.setNegativeButton("Nein Danke!", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
         public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Danke, dass sie mein Programm verwendet haben", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         onDestroy();
         }});
         builder2.setTitle("Speichern");
         builder2.show();    

     }
}
```

So it'll wait for user to say yes. If user cancel the dialog, then nothing's gonna happen i guess... (You can set a OnCancelListener for this situation of course)

Comment: I also tried this, but the super command must be right in OnPause method.

Comment: I've updated my answer... You can set a flag like this. It's not a perfect solution, but should do the trick ;)